# Angular ng-if holds reference to DOM element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-video

In an AngularJS project we have a `video` element that needs to toggle between playing and paused when the user hits <kbd>Space</kbd>. This might be a slightly naive implementation, but in a directive we've wired up a handler to the `$document` click event to toggle the video. It looks like this:

```
var video = element.find('video')[0];
$document.on('keypress', function(evt){
    if(evt.which === 32) {
       // toggle video 
       video[video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']();
    }
});
```

This has worked as expected so far. Only problem is that the directive is hidden or shown using an `ng-if` directive, but even after the the `ng-if` expression evaluates to `false`, the document click handler still holds onto the video reference. We discovered this when we still heard the video playing, even after it was no longer in the DOM.

I've created a [Plnkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/n8dALT9x3e9j2aZnchmB) to demonstrate the issue. The video disappears after 2.5 seconds, but you'll notice that you can press <kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle the video state even after it is removed from the DOM by `ng-if`.

For an answer, I'm looking for either:

1) A better, perhaps "more Angular" approach to solving this issue.

2) A way to detect that the video is no longer on the DOM so the reference can be deleted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular way would be to add this to the link function:

```
scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
  $document.off('keypress');
});
```

This is good practice in any directive event binding.  Eventually (as I understand) the garbage collector will go through and clear out these events, but if you are making events on items in ng-repeat....  then you potentially have a memory leak.

Comment: This is what I though of as well, but the video still seems to be "there". Try adding an `$interval` with function that starts/pauses the video - it will continue playing/stopping. If this is not the OP's problem, then this answer is definitely the right to do.

Comment: [This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b7NUXBMpUtEexRZoCY1w?p=preview) shows the `console.log(evt);` having no action when the space bar is pressed.

Comment: I added the $interval service (I forgot that was even there lol)